# Reading a Json in python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I need to get a particular **key:value** from a json file.

Code used to open json file :

```
import json
data = repr(open('file.json', 'rb').read())
print(data)
```

Output( **Json file**) :

> `b'b\'{"image":{"width":750,"height":1127,"orientation":1},"objects":[{"type":"face","boundingBox":{"x":132,"y":180,"height":619,"width":513},"landmarks":{"faceContour":[[162,375],[162,440],[165,504],[175,568],[193,628],[226,686],[265,740],[313,784],[373,799],[436,793],[494,758],[543,712],[586,660],[616,601],[631,534],[639,468],[645,400]],"noseBridge":[[387,396],[385,441],[381,485],[378,532]],"noseBall":[[322,547],[350,560],[380,572],[412,563],[442,554]],"eyebrowRight":[[419,348],[466,329],[516,325],[564,339],[595,377]],"eyebrowLeft":[[197,358],[224,325],[269,315],[316,325],[358,347]],"eyeRight":[[448,419],[479,404],[510,405],[539,416],[511,425],[480,424]],"eyeRightCenter":[[495,416]],"eyeLeft":[[242,402],[269,393],[299,396],[329,412],[297,414],[267,413]],"eyeLeftCenter":[[284,405]],"mouthOuter":[[269,596],[310,598],[349,598],[379,606],[411,601],[456,606],[502,609],[456,663],[412,684],[378,687],[345,680],[307,652]],"mouthInner":[[284,603],[349,610],[379,615],[411,613],[487,614],[412,652],[379,656],[348,648]]},"attributes":{"gender":"male","genderConfidence":0.8385,"age":24,"ageConfidence":0.8419,"emotion":"happiness","emotionConfidence":1.0,"emotionsAll":{"neutral":0.0,"sadness":0.0,"disgust":0.0,"anger":0.0,"surprise":0.0,"fear":0.0,"happiness":1.0},"pose":{"pitch":-5.7105,"roll":0.2941,"yaw":1.8646},"race":{"asian":0.0002,"black":0.0001,"white":0.9989},"eyewear":{"sunglasses":0.0,"glasses":0.0},"hair":{"color":{"blond":0.0,"black":0.9994,"brown":0.0},"cut":{"short":0.9999,"long":0.0,"bald":0.0},"facial":{"beard":0.0,"mustache":0.0,"stubble":0.2543}},"frontal":true}},{"type":"person","boundingBox":{"x":20,"y":60,"height":1053,"width":696}}],"requestId":"1239be0c782440bd828cee21dbc2baa1"}\'\r\n'`

From this Json file, I need to extract a particular **key:value**. For example, I need to get the emotionsAll (Key) from the file.

I tried using :

```
print(data['emotionsAll'][0]['neutral'])
```

error i got :

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\HP\Downloads\Final Project\getfile.py", line 6, in <module>
>     print(data['emotionsAll'][0]['neutral']) TypeError: string indices must be integers
> ```

So, Is there any other way to get a particular key:value ?

Comment: try `data['emotionsAll']['neutral']`. `emotionsAll` is not a list so you can't access it via integer indices.

Comment: Nope ! That was about how to open a json file . My question is how would i read them as like a dictionary :) @Fabian

Comment: Still i get : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP\Downloads\Final Project\getfile.py", line 5, in <module>
    data['emotionsAll']['neutral']
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: @Sai if you check you just read it in wrong ... if you open and load json format correctly you are able to access like dict...

Comment: tried opening :raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple things:

1 - the `emotionsAll` key is within the `objects` key, first element in the list `[0]`, `attributes` key

2 - Your json file was written with the bytes prefix, so when it's being read, it starts your string with `b'`. You can either a) have that file written without that mode by decoding/encoding, or just manipulate that string.

```
import json

data = repr(open('file.json', 'rb').read())

data = data.split('{', 1)[-1]
data = data.rsplit('}', 1)[0]

data = ''.join(['{', data, '}'])
jsonObj = json.loads(data)

print(jsonObj['objects'][0]['attributes']['emotionsAll']['neutral'])
```

**Output:**

```
print(jsonObj['objects'][0]['attributes']['emotionsAll']['neutral']) 
0.0
```

Comment: It Works only if the json file content is defined in the json_str . But when i used the same from a external json file (i.e data = repr(open('file.json', 'rb').read()) ) , I doesn't give the same !

Comment: @Sai, true, but I was addressing the other issue of `TypeError: string indices must be integers`. But maybe it's the binary mode that is causing the issue? Look at the edit in the solution and see if that works

Comment: data = repr(open('file.json', 'r').read()) works but once i try print(data['objects'][0]['attributes']['emotionsAll']['neutral'])  it doesnt return the value . Instead it gives a error : TypeError: string indices must be integers...... with open('file.json') as fp:
    data = json.load(fp) when i tried this ..  i got :::: Still the same : raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: I have Send the json file to your email . Please do check it :)

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Work fine now :)

Comment: I still think a better way would be to make sure that API json file is written without that bytes prefix, but in the mean time, this is a work around

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `json` package

Contents of `file.json`

```
{"image":{"width":750,"height":1127,"orientation":1},"objects":[{"type":"face","boundingBox":{"x":132,"y":180,"height":619,"width":513},"landmarks":{"faceContour":[[162,375],[162,440],[165,504],[175,568],[193,628],[226,686],[265,740],[313,784],[373,799],[436,793],[494,758],[543,712],[586,660],[616,601],[631,534],[639,468],[645,400]],"noseBridge":[[387,396],[385,441],[381,485],[378,532]],"noseBall":[[322,547],[350,560],[380,572],[412,563],[442,554]],"eyebrowRight":[[419,348],[466,329],[516,325],[564,339],[595,377]],"eyebrowLeft":[[197,358],[224,325],[269,315],[316,325],[358,347]],"eyeRight":[[448,419],[479,404],[510,405],[539,416],[511,425],[480,424]],"eyeRightCenter":[[495,416]],"eyeLeft":[[242,402],[269,393],[299,396],[329,412],[297,414],[267,413]],"eyeLeftCenter":[[284,405]],"mouthOuter":[[269,596],[310,598],[349,598],[379,606],[411,601],[456,606],[502,609],[456,663],[412,684],[378,687],[345,680],[307,652]],"mouthInner":[[284,603],[349,610],[379,615],[411,613],[487,614],[412,652],[379,656],[348,648]]},"attributes":{"gender":"male","genderConfidence":0.8385,"age":24,"ageConfidence":0.8419,"emotion":"happiness","emotionConfidence":1.0,"emotionsAll":{"neutral":0.0,"sadness":0.0,"disgust":0.0,"anger":0.0,"surprise":0.0,"fear":0.0,"happiness":1.0},"pose":{"pitch":-5.7105,"roll":0.2941,"yaw":1.8646},"race":{"asian":0.0002,"black":0.0001,"white":0.9989},"eyewear":{"sunglasses":0.0,"glasses":0.0},"hair":{"color":{"blond":0.0,"black":0.9994,"brown":0.0},"cut":{"short":0.9999,"long":0.0,"bald":0.0},"facial":{"beard":0.0,"mustache":0.0,"stubble":0.2543}},"frontal":true}},{"type":"person","boundingBox":{"x":20,"y":60,"height":1053,"width":696}}],"requestId":"1239be0c782440bd828cee21dbc2baa1"}
```

Code:

```
import json

with open('file.json', 'rb') as fp:
    json_data = json.load(fp)

print(json_data['objects'][0]['attributes']['emotionsAll']['neutral'])
```

Comment: raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: Will the update the answer soon

Comment: Sure and Thanks. Will be waiting for the respond

Comment: It's working fine for me. Try giving the absolute path of `file.json` file.

Comment: Still the same  : raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: Can you post your `file.json` contents?

Comment: I have added the `file.json` contents

Comment: I have printed the whole json file in my question . Do check the Output( Json file) above !

Comment: I think the problem lies with the way the data is stored in the `file.json` file. Copy the contents as I have displayed in my answer and then try running my code.

Comment: It works fine! But why doesn't it work with old content .Because I wont be able to edit each json file from a 100 files right?!

Comment: It's because `.json` file should contain only `json` content. Your output contains `b'b\'` and `\'\r\n'` which creates the problem while using `json.load()`.

Comment: How is the content being stored in the `files`. Can you share the code which writes the `json` data into the file?

Comment: `with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
    print(result, file=f)`

Comment: What is the type of `result`?

Comment: Its a API json file